# Cross-validation for random forest regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Let us image a dataset that is split into training and test sets. In order to estimate the hyperparameters of a model I would perform GridSearchCV using only the train data and performing cross-validation. As far as I understand the usage of the complete data set (i.e before the split into train and test) would lead to data leakage.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0) 
      
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110],
    'max_features': [2, 3],
    'min_samples_leaf': [2, 3, 4, 5],
    'min_samples_split': [8, 10, 12],
    'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 400]}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0), param_grid=param_grid,
                           cv=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1))

grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

This would give me the best parameters. I would now use these parameters for my random forest regressor. Subsequently I would perform a cross-validation in order to estimate the performance of the model and the prediction using the test set.

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap = grid_search.best_params_['bootstrap'],
                           n_estimators = grid_search.best_params_['n_estimators'],
                           max_features = grid_search.best_params_['max_features'],
                           max_depth = grid_search.best_params_['max_depth'],
                           min_samples_leaf = grid_search.best_params_['min_samples_leaf'],
                           min_samples_split = grid_search.best_params_['min_samples_split'],
                           random_state = 0)
    
rf.fit(x_train, y_train)

n_scores = cross_val_score(rf, x_train, y_train,
                           cv=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)).mean()

prediction = rf.predict(x_test)
```

The last step could probably replaced by

```
n_scores = cross_val_score(grid_search, x_train, y_train,
                           cv=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)).mean()
grid_search.predict(x_test)
```

Do i need another cross-validation to estimate the performance of the model (I was thinking about a [nested cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html)) or is this step carried within the first grid search?

In addition: What would be the appropriate scoring metric?

Comment: You forgot to state your question/problem

Comment: About the scoring metric: it depends (whether data is balanced or not, the problem you are trying to model...)

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to run `cross_val_score` again. You have already done that with `GridSearchCV`. With your second part, even though you initiated the model with the best params, you are still doing cross validation on the same KFolds , so you will get the same result. To illustrate :

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

x,y = make_regression(n_samples=500, random_state=99)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0) 
      
param_grid = {
    'max_depth': [5,10,20],
    'max_features' : [5,10,20],
    'n_estimators': [20,50]}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0), 
param_grid=param_grid,cv=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1))


grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

This is the best score :

```
grid_search.best_score_
0.4738885133981142
```

If we run your code, we get the same score , so you are better off without this step:

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(
                           n_estimators = grid_search.best_params_['n_estimators'],
                           max_features = grid_search.best_params_['max_features'],
                           max_depth = grid_search.best_params_['max_depth'],
                           random_state = 0)
    
rf.fit(x_train, y_train)

n_scores = cross_val_score(rf, x_train, y_train,
                           cv=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)).mean()

n_scores
0.4738885133981142
```

As for the metric to score your model, it makes sense to use the same metric used in gridSearchCV, because you optimized the model based on that, you can do:

```
grid_search.score(x_test,y_test)
0.5043694231845961
```

Since you did not specify a scoring method with GridSearchCV, it will use the default scoring in [RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score), which is R^2 . If you would like use another scoring method, for example rmse , you should specify it when you train the model:

```
GridSearchCV(estimator=RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0), 
param_grid=param_grid,cv=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1),
scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error")
```